# New session is created when verifying a user via email from a mobile device

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-6

I am working on Laravel (6.2) project. When new user is created, a verification email is sent to them via Laravel built-in verification mechanism. I am using some previously stored values in session to created a URL and redirect the user to it after verifying in verify function in Verification Controller. Now the problem is when using a mobile device to verify (clicking on verify link) a new session is created. Hence, can't access the values and because that the first part of the URL is missing, which results in endless redirections loop. But when verifying with a laptop or a desktop everything is working fine.

I tried to change the session driver from 'cookie' to 'database' or 'file' and I tried to change 'same_site' in config file to 'lax' but the issue remained.

This is my verify function:

```
public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find($request->route('id'));

        if (!hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($user->getEmailForVerification()))) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }
        if ($user->markEmailAsVerified()){
            if(session()->get('user_data.client_mac_address')){
                AssociateUsers::dispatch($user,session()->get('user_data.client_mac_address'));
            }
            event(new Verified($user));
        }
        
        $campaign           = Campaign::getActiveCampaign(null,$request->campaign_id);
        $continueUrl        = Campaign::getActiveCampaignUrl('redirection',optional($campaign)->id);

        if($campaign){
            if($campaign->redirections->count() >= $campaign->budget->no_of_redirections){
                unset($campaign);
            }
        }
    
        if(isset($campaign)){
            CampaignHistory::addHistory($campaign->id,$request->branch_id,$request->device_id,$request->network_id,'redirection');
        }

        $webUrl = session()->get('user_data.base_grant_url') . "?continue_url=" . $continueUrl . "&duration=3600";

        $request->session()->forget('grant_token');  
        return redirect()->away($webUrl);

    }
```

Note that in either way the user gets verified. Anyone has any idea on what is going on here?

**Edited**

The application is to manage small networks (Mostly WiFi) like in restaurant and cafés via Meraki APIs. So it is assumed that the user will verify their email shortly after registration in the splash page to gain access to the network. Some of the information stored in the session are necessary to grant the user access to the network. It is implied in a [Meraki Document](https://meraki.cisco.com/lib/pdf/meraki_whitepaper_captive_portal.pdf) (page 7) that these information should be saved in a session.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you storing data into the session at this point in the first place? The verification might not happen right away, the user might do it later, or from a different device than they one the triggered the process from to begin with.

Comment: as CBroe commented, sessions are not a good solution here. Often on mobile devices the email app uses another browser, so the session does not exist there.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your reply. I have updated my post. Please check.

Comment: Needs some more debugging then, I suppose. Have you checked what setcookie/cookie headers are present in requests & responses? Do things change when you set samesite to none (will also require Secure to be set/HTTPS to be used)?

Comment: @CBroe I think the issue is that when connecting to a WiFi via mobile the splash page (Registration page) is opened in a web view. Then when verify link is clicked in the email, it opens in the default browser, which cause creating a new session. On the other hand, when connecting to a WiFi via a computer, the splash page is opened on the default browser directly, which in most cases is also used for verifying too. The only difference between the processes of validating from a mobile and a computer is the session. Every thing else is identical email service provider, used route, function, etc

Comment: Well then I don’t see how this _should_ work, the web view and the browser are not going to share any cookies. Explicitly passing the session id via URL (if you can get the system to include that in the verify link) might be the only viable option then.